# How do I vertically align my UILabel within a UITableViewCell, when using lineHeightMultiple to control leading between lines?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, vertical-alignment, nsattributedstring

I have a multiline UILabel in a UITableViewCell. I want to control the spacing between the lines, to compress the lines a bit closer together. I've read that the only way to control that "leading" is with Attributed Strings. So I've done this by making the label attributed instead of plain text, and then I set the lineHeightMultiple to 0.7 to compress the lines:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 0.7;
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

NSDictionary *attrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:15.0], NSFontAttributeName, paragraphStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Here is some long text that will wrap to two lines." attributes:attrs];

[cell.textLabel setAttributedText:attributedText];
```

The problem is, now the overall label is not centered vertically within the UITableViewCell.

How can I fix this? In the attachment below, you can see what I mean. The "compressed" multiline UILabel is higher up in each row than it should be, and doesn't vertically align with the arrow indicator on the right side any more.

[image: example]

Comment: I think increasing y position of UILable when you add it to UITableViewCell can make your work done, It is the easiest way I came out with. Many be other other options are also available.

Comment: @Yuvrajsinh, i would vote for your answer for the bounty if you placed it in an answer. it might also be possible to adjust the lineSpacing, paragraphSpacingBefore and paragraphSpacing attributes instead of doing this in order for the text to appear as desired in the middle of the UILabel text area.

Comment: The new answer should be accepted as the correct one don't you think?

Comment: @hfossli It sounds like the better solution, which is why I marked it up, but I haven't had a chance to test it out in my code yet, which is why I haven't marked it as the solution yet. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line height multiple changes the line hight of all lines, including the first line, so it all rides a little high in your label. What you really want is to adjust the line spacing, so the second line's starting base line is a little closer than the default.

Try replacing:

```
paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 0.7;
```

with:

```
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = -5.0;
```

Adjust the line spacing value to taste.

Comment: Thank you! I swear I tried messing around with lineSpacing in lieu of lineHeightMultiple, but could never get it to work properly (I think perhaps I was trying positive integers instead of negative)!

Comment: Not sure this solution is a good idea. From NSMutableParagraphStyle interface: "@property(readonly) CGFloat lineSpacing; /* "Leading": distance between the bottom of one line fragment and top of next (applied between lines in the same container). Can't be negative. This value is included in the line fragment heights in layout manager. */"

Comment: (Voted down due to setting an arbitrary value does not always help)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that negative values for lineSpacing are a no go.

Answer (score 1):

Both `UITextDrawing` and `Core Text` does this. I think it is superstrange.. Instead of using an arbitrary value for `lineSpacing` - I say calculate this with `Core Text` and figure out the actual offset like this

```
+ (CGFloat)offsetForAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)attributedString drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect];
    CFRange fullRange = CFRangeMake(0, [attributedString length]);
    CTFramesetterRef framesetterRef = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)attributedString);
    CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetterRef, fullRange, path.CGPath, NULL);
    CFArrayRef lineArrayRef = CTFrameGetLines(frameRef);
    CFIndex lineCount = CFArrayGetCount(lineArrayRef);
    CGPoint lineOrigins[lineCount];
    CTFrameGetLineOrigins(frameRef, CFRangeMake(0, lineCount), lineOrigins);

    CGFloat offsetDueToLineHeight = 0.0;

    if(lineCount > 0)
    {
        CTLineRef firstLine = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(lineArrayRef, 0);
        CGFloat ascent, descent, leading;
        CTLineGetTypographicBounds(firstLine, &ascent, &descent, &leading);
        offsetDueToLineHeight = rect.size.height - lineOrigins[0].y - ascent;
    }

    CFRelease(frameRef);
    CFRelease(framesetterRef);

    return offsetDueToLineHeight;
}
```

This value works for both `UITextDrawing` and `Core Text`.